# How to import dataset from SQL Server via VPN connection

Tags: sql-server, database, vpn

I need to import dataset from a remote SQL Server using a VPN connection. I would like to know how to proceed. I have no experience in servers.

I am using a shiny app to read and process csv files. Now I am getting a bit more ambitious and I would like to upload directly my data from a remote SQL server. I communicate to this server via a VPN connection.

Comment: "SQL server" means Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

When you have access to the database via SSMS, You can import file.

1. you choose the database that you want to import file into.
2. right click the database and find "Import Data" option under
   tasks.
3. You will be able to choose file type that you are
   trying to import. For the Txt, and csv file, please use Flat File
   Source as Data Source.